# Write value to hidden element selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to write ",10" to
Value parameter here:

```
<input id="import_product_categories" type="hidden" value="" name="import_params[category_ids]"></input>
```

Using selenium I know it needs to be done by Javascript and for some reason the following code from another answer here in stackoverflow doesn't work

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('import_product_categories').value+=',10'")
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What does it do? What doesn't it do? What errors do you get? In what browser? In what version of that browser? In what version of Selenium? Why don't you do whatever a user needs to do to make that element *visible* and *usable* and then you don't need to use Javascript **at all**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small error in the java scipt code. All the lines in js also ends with ; which you have missed. Also if you want to append text to the already existing value in the textbox execute the following js code

```
String setText = "document.getElementById('import_product_categories').value += 'hello';";
```

If you do not want to append the text then execute this one.

```
String setText = "document.getElementById('import_product_categories').value += 'hello';";
```